# .rst (reStructuredText) files not rendered in the browser

Tags: restructuredtext

I was told by some people to write my documentation files in .rst since this format was apparently already rendered by default in browsers like Firefox.

Now, I open one such file on Firefox under Windows, but it turns out nothing is rendered, just plain text. I've tried opening the same file under my Virtual Machine running Ubuntu, still nothing.

Is there something else that needs to be installed to have a nice rendered view of those rst files ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at this time, browsers do not support previewing restructuredtext.

You may have been told that there are online tools or plugins.

There are Chrome plugins:  google search for "**restructuredtext bowser plugin**".

There are some online applications (if you're willing to trust them):  google search for "**restructuredtext viewer**".

Finally, you can find applications like [Remarkable](https://remarkableapp.github.io).